# Update serviceAnnotations after istio installation

Tags: istio, amazon-eks

I installed istio using istioctl on AWS EKS cluster.

```
**Version**
EKS : 1.21
Istio : 1.11.1
```

```
**Command**
# istioctl install -y -f istio-manifest.yaml
```

```
**istio-manifest.yaml**
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          hpaSpec:
            minReplicas: 1
            maxReplicas: 3
          serviceAnnotations:
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: 'test-istio'
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet-xxxxx,subnet-xxxxx"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "external"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "ip"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-west-1:xxxxx:certificate/xxxxx"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes: "preserve_client_ip.enabled=false"
          service:
            ports:
              - name: status
                protocol: TCP
                port: 15021
                targetPort: 15021
              - name: https
                protocol: TCP
                port: 443
                targetPort: 8443
              - name: grpc
                protocol: TCP
                port: 9090
                targetPort: 9090
```

An NLB was created successfully. After istio installed, I changed preserve_client_ip.enabled from false to true and then ran the installation command again. However the attribute of the NLB was not changed, still false. Of course, AWS Load Balancer Controller was installed correctly.

How can I change the attribute after istio installation?

Comment: Hmm, I have checked with my `IstioOperator` resource and I've modified `aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags` which updated tags on my classic load balancer so definitely changing the annotation after the lb creation works at least for some annotations on the classic lb. I wonder what is responsible for updating the load balancer - is it `aws-node` or something on the control panel side? Maybe they would have some errors in their logs.

Comment: Kubernetes manifest for the load balancer controller has something wrong. When I installed it with helm, it worked. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html

Comment: @honillusion Have you resolved this issue? Based on your comment it looks like yes. You can [answer to your own question and accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it will be helpful for the community who will face the same issue.